# Poor performance of unpickling files with uWSGI

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, uwsgi

I have to unpickle around 200 files, each containing a custom class containing a `numpu.ndarray` (shape 500x32) and some metadata (few int and str).
Each file's size is around 50ko.

Here is the simplified code:

```
#!venv/bin/python3


import random
import pickle

from pathlib import Path


# real live : around 200 files
filenames = ["file1.pickle", "file2.pickle"]
filepaths = [Path(fn) for fn in filenames]


# read all the files and keep them in a list of bytes
# This is for debug purposes : I want to be sure that the unpicking is 
# the time-consuming line.
str_datas = []
for filename in filepaths:
    str_data = filename.read_bytes()
    str_datas.append(str_data)

# shuffle for a reason, see below
random.shuffle(str_datas)

# unpickle the read data
datas = []
num = 0
for str_data in str_datas:
    num += 1
    print(num)
    data = pickle.loads(str_data)  # <---- this line takes 0.02s or 5s !! (see bellow)
    datas.append(data)
```

As it, this codes works well, and each unpicking takes ~0.02s.

BUT. In my real live app, it is embedded in uWSGI and I have a very strange behavior.

Each time I run the code, one (and only one) unpickle takes 5s instead of 0.02s. Since the strings are shuffled, it is always a different one.

More strange : each time, the long unpicking is between the 55th and the 63th unpickling.

I do not parallelize the unpickling. Maybe uwsgi does ?

Any ideas ?

EDIT 1 : I know the line taking much time for two reasons:

1. I clearly see the 60 first "print" arriving at once, and the 61th taking much more time.
2. I added some `print(time.time())` everywhere.

EDIT 2 : This is not an IO issue. To be sure, I read the all the files in a first loop, and then I only depickle them in a second loop.

Comment: Can you post relevant part of uWSGI as well?

Answer (score 0):

uWSGI cannot affect Python's pickling behaviour. It's likely something else in your system is causing the issue, like poor performance of IO or lack of caches. Because the question lacks details, like how to repeat the issue or performance analysis made with profiler, it is impossible to tell.

Never the less, You should not do long-running operations in HTTP request/response handlers. Unpickling 200 files sounds like something you do not want to do.

Instead

- Run one time batch job or cron (Dramatiq, Celery) process that prepares the data and stores it in e.g. Redis or temporary files
- uWSGI handler reads the data directly and does not try to do any processing during the HTTP request handling
- Design your APIs so that uWSGI does not need to unpickle 200 files in one request
- Use an alternative data format than pickling. If it's data only you can use formats like Parquet, CSV, etc.